# which CMS or component or module Use to sell digital products that need treatment after the clients buys

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, store, product, digital

I wanna sell products online it's a service.
Clients goes on the site he chooses the product after he purchases it he will log in in his frontend area and he will add some files to complete his order. 
and once the files and the informations are added to his order. the stuff will work on his case and deliver him a file when work done. that ile can be sended by mail or by downloading it from the frontend. 
the product has many states :  1-purchased 2-waiting for additional files from client 3-files accepted and working on it 4- work done files ready to download

I tried many things like virtuemart on joomla , ubercart on drupal, magento, prestashop, wpecommerce on wordpress most of them can afford digital products for instant download but not services that need a delay (tratment of the order) time before the products are ready for download.

Regards
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Your needs are very specific. So you need to use Virtuemart (Joomla), for example, as a base and code the part you need :
- multi-upload form
- new product states : waiting for additional files from client,...

No matter the choosen solution (joomla, magento,...), you need to have a good skill in this solution and in web dev (php, mysql, html)!

Good luck!